# Return a string from VBS to a batch file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd

I have a batch file which is running a VBS file during its execution. The VBS file is input some variables from user and generate a string variable. Now, I wants after VBS script finished it should return that string variable to batch file, which can be used in batch file.

I read several tutorials but, I am unable to do this. How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('cscript.exe yourFile.vbs') do (
    rem Add processing of yous script here 
   )
```

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion dealys variables expansion intill execution time. This allows using variables in for loops. Variable value is is obtained like !var_name!, not %var_name%.

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('cscript.exe yourFile.vbs') do ( 
   executes your vbs file and uses its putput in for loop. cscript.exe is the command line vbs interpreter. Each line of 'cscript.exe yourFile.vbs' will be stored in %%a variable. This is the loop variable name.

Hope this clarifies.

Comment: You missed to add, for example: `echo The value returned by VBS is: %%a`

Comment: Also how to send variable from VBS file?

Comment: Added some explanations. Sorry, but I don't understand the sentence "Also how to send variable from VBS file?". Could you please explain?

Comment: Means the code that should be used in the VBS file to return the value.

Comment: Ok, finally found that `    WScript.StdOut.Write "Hello World"`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that shows you how to do it.

You just have to echo out the answer from the vbs and read it using for.

```
call :Convertbytes 102523432123 MB free
exit /b

:ConvertBytes bytes unit ret
setlocal
if "%~2" EQU "KB" set val=/1024
if "%~2" EQU "MB" set val=/1024/1024
if "%~2" EQU "GB" set val=/1024/1024/1024
if "%~2" EQU "TB" set val=/1024/1024/1024/1024
> %temp%\tmp.vbs echo wsh.echo FormatNumber(eval(%~1%val%),0)
for /f "delims=" %%a in ( 
  'cscript //nologo %temp%\tmp.vbs' 
) do endlocal & set %~3=%%a
del %temp%\tmp.vbs
exit /b
```